# Question about expressing logarithms

Tags: logarithms

If logb (a) = m and logy (b) = c, then find loga (y) in terms of variable c and m

This is what I have so far

logb (a) = log a / log b

logy (b) = log b / log y

=(log a / log b)(log b / log y)

= log a / log y

= logy (a)

I don't know what to do from this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously :
$\log_{a}y = \frac{\log_{b}y}{\log_{b}a}$ 
i= $\frac{1}{cm}$

Comment: thanks, answered my question

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint:

$$\log_ba=\frac{\log b}{\log a}=m$$
$$\log_ya=\frac{\log a}{\log y}=c$$